# Display SVG icons in polygon layer using PyQGIS3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, svg

I have this code to set SVG icons only for selected features. It works, but only with point geometry, while I have a layer with polygon geometry. How can I modify this code to works also with polygon geometry?

```
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()

svgStyle = {}
svgStyle['name'] = path
svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
svgStyle['size'] = '15'
symbolLayer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer.create(svgStyle)

symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType()) 
symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbolLayer)

renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
rule.setLabel('test')
rule.setFilterExpression('is_selected()')
root_rule.appendChild(rule) 

root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
vlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

I thought that probably it's not possible to apply a SvgMarkerSymbol to a polygon layer and that I have to use before `QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer` is the way to go.
You will have a RuleBase renderer, with the following structure

- `QgsFillSymbol` *[default rule (always)]*

  - `QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer`
- `QgsFillSymbol` *[is_selected() rule]*

  - `QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer`

    - `QgsMarkerSymbol`

      - `QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer`

```
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()

# Create SVG marker symbol
svgStyle = {
    "name": "path/to/image.svg",
    "outline": "#000000",
    "size": "15",
}
svgLayer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer.create(svgStyle)
svgSymbol = QgsMarkerSymbol()
svgSymbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, svgLayer)

# Default symbol, for unselected polygons
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType())

# Centroid fill symbol for selected polygons
centroid = QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayer()
centroid.setSubSymbol(svgSymbol)
selectedSymbol = QgsFillSymbol()
selectedSymbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, centroid)

# Create renderer
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
rule = QgsRuleBasedRenderer.Rule(
    selectedSymbol, label="Selected", filterExp="is_selected()"
)
renderer.rootRule().appendChild(rule)
vlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Comment: I shouldn't say it, but I love you