# How to embed a SVG symbol with pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, svg

In a python QGIS plugin, how can I embed a SVG symbol, as if I used the 'Embed file' function in a svg marker symbology in QGIS ?

Comment: I think this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350830/display-svg-icons-in-polygon-layer-using-pyqgis3

can help you to solve the issue

Comment: No. I know how to add a svg symbol layer, but my question is how to embed the svg file into the symbology definition: at the end we don't need the svg file anymore, the svg description should be embedded into the symbology definition.